# How to close connection created with WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open?

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, connection-pooling, webmatrix

I'm using the Database class from webmatrix in a windows service. (And debugging in a winform causes same error)

The error I receive (after running for a while) is:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool. This may have occured because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

This should be solved by using using statements to make sure all connections are closed. ( [as described in this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server)) But I've recently started using also the WebMatrix database class, and it does not seem to close the connections I open with it.

**Question is: How to close connections created with the Database class from WebMatrix?**

Using this code:

```
Public Shared Function GetProperty(pid As Integer, propertyName As String) As String
    Dim db = Database.Open("SSEConnectionString")
    Dim item = db.QuerySingle("select PropertyValue from eConfiguration where PID=@0 and PropertyName=@1", pid, propertyName)
    Dim retVal = item.PropertyValue
    db.Connection.Close()
    db.Close()
    Return retVal
End Function
```

Each time I run this code I get a new entry in my **sys.sysprocesses** table (and from what I've figured out, this is indicating a new connection is created and maintained)

My connectionstring looks like this:

> ```
> <add name="SSEConnectionString" connectionString="Data
> ```
>
> Source=123.45.67.890;Initial Catalog=SSE;User
>   ID=+++;Password=+++;Connect Timeout=5;Application Name=SSE_Service"
>               providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: [Asked a second question regarding the sysprocesses table - unsure if it helps in debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388006/sysprocesses-table-will-it-help-me-debug-connection-pooling-issues)

Thanks for any help

**Edit2: Arghhhhh.... I just found what was causing the error - and it's only related to myself. I forgot to close a connection. :-(**

Larsi

Comment: This is maybe not related with webmatrix - changed to standard ado and see same beavior, will update question when I figure out the reason for the error

Comment: Nobody but me to blame for this - simply forgot to to a db.close deep down in my spagetti

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
db.Connection.Close()
db.Close()
```