# How do I know actual SQL Server client side connection pool utilization?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure-sql-database

My C# code uses `SqlConnection` to connect to SQL Azure. Sometimes I will face the following:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection
from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were
in use and max pool size was reached.
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(
    DbConnection owningConnection)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(
    DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
// my code calling SqlConnection.Open()
```

I'd like to find why I'm facing this exception. The exception is likely because I've exhausted the connection pool, but I'm not completely sure and if I were sure I'd like to know how I got there.

Is is possible for my code to obtain the maximum pool size and current pool utilization (number of used and unused connections)?

Comment: [Max Pool Size Setting and Federations in Windows Azure SQL Database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2012/09/07/max-pool-size-setting-and-federations-in-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx)

Comment: @Habib: That thing is per-connection and it doesn't say how many connections I already have.

Answer (score 3):

The Max number of connections for SQL Azure database is 180 connections. This is a hard limit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394114.aspx

```
-- monitor connections
SELECT
      e.connection_id,
      s.session_id,
      s.login_name,
      s.last_request_end_time,
      s.cpu_time
FROM
      sys.dm_exec_sessions s
      INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections e
      ON s.session_id = e.session_id
GO
```

This query will allow to see the current connections. The link above also has some really useful querys for working out where connections are coming from.

I use this query as part of diagnostics setup and reporting which we run in cron job to make sure we are not heading towards an outage.

Max pool as already pointed out will help, but this depends on the number of compute in front of SQL Azure.

When you get this type of problem, you need to work out if you have a connection issue in terms of closing or that you need to start to look at more advanced solutions like sharding.

hths, James

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server).

Although max pool size, if not specified, is 100.

Comment: That doesn't say anything about the number of connections being used.

Comment: Just provided the link for some information on the **Exception** that you are getting, so that you can solve the problem. But yes that doesnot specify how you can detect the pool size through code.

Comment: I don't want to "solve my problem", I want to know the utilization.