# Configure EF6 to use varchar as default instead of nvarchar?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I know I can add a Data Annotation to each property to set it's column type to `VARCHAR` but I have hundreds of columns I want to be `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR` is there some way to setup EF6 to make this the default?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looking up EF conventions, I think you can do something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("varchar"));
```

I largely ripped this off from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164#order and haven't tested it.

[Edit:] As @Shimmy points out in the comments, there's also `c => c.IsUnicode(false)` which appears to do the same thing without hardcoding a column type.

Comment: Do you know if this will override the Data Annotations? I have some annotations to set a few columns to `CHAR`

Comment: It looks like the data annotations will take precedence as they are a more specific setting (most specific wins).

Comment: @Jimmy, what's the difference between the setting in your answer and `c.IsUnicode(false)`?

Comment: @Shimmy, my answer sets the column type explicitly, whereas IsUnicode looks like a more fluent API to describe the intent.  Technically, the implementation of IsUnicode could probably determine the most suitable column type, and also evolve over time if new types were introduced, or account for different supported types in different versions of SQL (although in this case I think everything supports varchar/nvarchar).

Comment: @Jimmy, so currently, when working against SQL-Server, do you know if `IsUnicode` will make it generate a `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`?

Comment: @Shimmy it looks that way, see line 920 in this file: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlProviderServices.cs

Comment: @Jimmy thanks for nailing it out! I see it in the method `GetStringDbType`, no line numbers in CodePlex...

Comment: Disabling Unicode just to change from NVarchar to Varchar is a bad idea if you need to store unicode data like non-english text.
Also it seems rather obscure. In that case I much prefer the HasColumnType("varchar") property - it does what it's supposed to without obscure side-effects.

Comment: @Gertsen It's all about which one you want to be the default. if you want the default to be `varchar` and then be forced to use `HasColumnType("nvarchar")` or something, well then that's a main effect which is the exact inverse of the current state of affairs; no side-effects going on here!

Comment: Using `IsUnicode` will allow the column to be `char` (if `IsFixedLength` is set) or `varchar`, whereas `HasColumnType("varchar")` will potentially override `char` to `varchar`.

Comment: This is great but doesn't work for EF Core, is there an equivalent?

Comment: @SBFrancies - actually, from what I can tell, .IsUnicode() does work in EF Core.  I'm using EF Core 2.0.  Running a migration after adding it changed my nvarchar columns to varchar.  Or do you mean that there is no IsFIxedLength() in order to generate a "char" column?

Comment: @BioData41 I think my comment was from before the edit which added the .IsUnicode solution. I was referring to the original answer.

Comment: @ErikE I've tried `property.SetIsUnicode(false)` and it's still NVARCHAR in the generated migration .cs file... EF7.

Comment: @Alexander Hmmm I don't know what to tell you. I haven't worked with EF since about the time I last commented.

Comment: @ErikE it turned out there was another type of oproperty to check. I was not aware, since it was a 3rd party lib :) In fact, the solution does work.