# Getting an Error: InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, fluentvalidation

I get the error: InvalidOperationException while using the below mentioned code:

```
using (MunimPlusContext context = new MunimPlusContext())
{
    var dbGroup = context.GroupSet
                         .Where(x => x.GroupName.ToLower() == groupName.ToLower())
                         .SingleOrDefault();

    if (dbGroup == null)
        return true;
    else
        return dbGroup.GroupId == group.GroupId;
}
```

The detail provided by the error is:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

### What I have tried:

1. I used the below mentioned line of code to overcome this error:

   context.Database.Connection.Open();
2. I also used SQL Profiler which fires the query as follows, but I don't understand the generated SQL:

   exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
       [Extent1].[GroupId] AS [GroupId], 
       [Extent1].[GroupName] AS [GroupName], 
       [Extent1].[Alias] AS [Alias], 
       [Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
       [Extent1].[IsSystemGroup] AS [IsSystemGroup], 
       [Extent1].[NatureOfGroupId] AS [NatureOfGroupId], 
       [Extent1].[EffectId] AS [EffectId], 
       [Extent1].[BankDetailsVisibility] AS [BankDetailsVisibility], 
       [Extent1].[CreditLimitsVisibility] AS [CreditLimitsVisibility], 
       [Extent1].[GeneralDetailsVisibility] AS [GeneralDetailsVisibility], 
       [Extent1].[ContactDetailsVisibility] AS [ContactDetailsVisibility], 
       [Extent1].[TaxInformationVisibility] AS [TaxInformationVisibility]
       FROM [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent1]
       WHERE ((LOWER([Extent1].[GroupName])) = (LOWER(@p__linq__0))) OR ((LOWER([Extent1].[GroupName]) IS NULL) AND (LOWER(@p__linq__0) IS NULL))',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'Primary'
   go

### When I get this error:

When I am trying to check in the database for duplicates using FluentValidation as follows, I get this error:

```
RuleFor(obj => obj.GroupName).Must(UniqueName)
                             .WithMessage("Group with same name already exists. Please choose a different Group name");
```

Here is the method UniqueName which is the source of error:

```
private bool UniqueName(Group group, string groupName)
{
    using (MunimPlusContext context = new MunimPlusContext())
    {
        var dbGroup = context.GroupSet
                             .Where(x => x.GroupName.ToLower() == groupName.ToLower())
                             .SingleOrDefault();

        if (dbGroup == null)
            return true;
        else
            return dbGroup.GroupId == group.GroupId;
    }
}
```

### Update:

Here is the full stack trace:

> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   MunimPlus.Entities.Group.GroupValidator.UniqueName(Group group, String
>   groupName) in
>   H:\Work\Trial\New\MunimPlus\MunimPlusSolution\MunimPlus.Entities\Group.cs:line
>   274    at
>   FluentValidation.DefaultValidatorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4`2.b__3(T
>   x, TProperty val, PropertyValidatorContext propertyValidatorContext)
>   in
>   c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\DefaultValidatorExtensions.cs:line
>   219    at
>   FluentValidation.DefaultValidatorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<Must>b__6(Object
>   instance, Object property, PropertyValidatorContext
>   propertyValidatorContext) in
>   c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\DefaultValidatorExtensions.cs:line
>   235    at
>   FluentValidation.Validators.PredicateValidator.IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext
>   context) in
>   c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Validators\PredicateValidator.cs:line
>   37    at
>   FluentValidation.Validators.PropertyValidator.Validate(PropertyValidatorContext
>   context) in
>   c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Validators\PropertyValidator.cs:line
>   71    at
>   FluentValidation.Internal.PropertyRule.InvokePropertyValidator(ValidationContext
>   context, IPropertyValidator validator, String propertyName) in
>   c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Internal\PropertyRule.cs:line
>   346    at
>   FluentValidation.Internal.PropertyRule.<Validate>d__10.MoveNext() in
>   c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Internal\PropertyRule.cs:line
>   234    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.Validate(ValidationContext`1
>   context) in
>   c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\AbstractValidator.cs:line
>   113    at FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.Validate(T instance) in
>   c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\AbstractValidator.cs:line
>   94    at
>   FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.FluentValidation.IValidator.Validate(Object
>   instance) in
>   c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\AbstractValidator.cs:line
>   55    at Core.Common.Core.EntityBase.Validate() in
>   H:\Work\Trial\New\Core\Core.Common\Core\EntityBase.cs:line 206    at
>   Core.Common.Core.EntityBase..ctor() in
>   H:\Work\Trial\New\Core\Core.Common\Core\EntityBase.cs:line 25    at
>   MunimPlus.Entities.Group..ctor()    at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper
>   )    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2
>   constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper)

### Update1:

If I don't use `context.Database.Connection.Open()`, then I get another error saying that:

> Underlying Provider failed to Open.

But before this call to the database I have some other calls where its working fine.

If I remove this validation, then also my project works fine.

Still I would like to show my connection string here:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MunimPlus" 
       connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Max;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

### Update 2:

Got some hint on problem but not solution.

I have a base class called EntityBase. All of my Entities inherits from EntityBase. So my Group class will look something like:

```
public class Group : EntityBase
{

    Fields.....

    Properties....

    class GroupValidator : AbstractValidator<T>
    {
        public GroupValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(obj => obj.GroupName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Group name cannot be empty.");
            RuleFor(obj => obj.GroupName).Must(UniqueName).WithMessage("Group with same name already exists. Please choose a different Group name");
            RuleFor(obj => obj.ParentId).NotNull().WithMessage("Please select the group under which this group will appear")
                                        .GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Please select a valid/existing group name");
        }

        private bool UniqueName(Group group, string groupName)
        {
            if (groupName == null)
                groupName = "";

            using (MunimPlusContext context = new MunimPlusContext())
            {
                Group dbGroup = context.GroupSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName.ToLower() == groupName.ToLower());

                if (dbGroup == null)
                    return true;
                else
                    return dbGroup.GroupId == group.GroupId;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override IValidator GetValidator()
    {
        return new GroupValidator();
    }

}
```

Look at the last method called GetValidator, it is an overridden version of virtual method defined in EntityBase class.

Now, a part of EntityBase class looks like:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{

    public EntityBase()
    {
        _Validator = GetValidator();
        Validate();
    }

    protected IValidator _Validator = null;

    protected IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> _ValidationErrors = null;

    protected virtual IValidator GetValidator()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> ValidationErrors
    {
        get { return _ValidationErrors; }
        set { }
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        if (_Validator != null)
        {
            ValidationResult results = _Validator.Validate(this);
            _ValidationErrors = results.Errors;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ValidationErrors != null && _ValidationErrors.Count() > 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now inside CarValidator class's UniqueName method's line

```
Group dbGroup = context.GroupSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName.ToLower() == groupName.ToLower());
```

for each group a new instance is created and validated due to the EntityBase class. So, cursor runs across `using(MunimPlusContext context = new MunimPlusContext)` but never closes the connection as it goes deeper and deeper to create new instances of group, as a result maximum connections in database is reached. Thus I get connection pooling problem.

When I increased Max Pool Size to 999, I got another error StackOverFlowException.

### Demo Project reproducing the issue:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bM252VXdveVVMMzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How big is `GroupSet`? Putting the `ToLower()` in your `Where` will result in lowercasing in the query, which could cause massive performance issues.

Comment: You can remove the `Where` entirely. `context.GroupSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.GroupName.ToLower() == groupName.ToLower())` you could also put the `groupName.ToLower()` in a local. otherwise the `.ToLower()` is called on every check; which is meaningless.

Comment: @DionV. GroupSet only contains 28 records......

Comment: @diemaus I have tried the code that you suggested but I got the same result. Also, I have updated my question with Stack Trace. Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: @DionV. I have updated my question with the stack trace. Can you please check it?

Comment: That error about getting a timeout before getting a connection means your program is having trouble connecting to the database.  Usually this means your connection string is pointed to the wrong place, an office VPN is down, the db server isn't responding, etc.

Comment: @Vishal Good that you provided the stacktrace, could you also provide the connectionstring?

Comment: @Becuzz I got the error The underlying provider failed on Open. Before using context.Database.Connection.Open(). But if you tell that there might be connection string issue, then I am very much sure that my connection string is 100% right, as I am getting the data before this call. Still I will update my question with Connection String.

Comment: @DionV. I have updated my question with connection string.

Comment: @Becuzz Can you please take a look at the Updated question???

Comment: Both of those errors point to the fact that it can't open a connection to the database.  If you are absolutely positive that your connection string is correct, you may have a connection pool problem.  As the first error suggests "This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

Comment: @Becuzz I am 100% sure that my connection string is correct. That means I have a connection pool problem. What are the steps that you suggest to solve it?

Comment: Start here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server]

Comment: @Becuzz Thanks for the link. I have checked it but can't get anything out of it. Still I will work on it and post my answer here If I am able to solve the problem....

Comment: @DionV. I have got the original problem but not the solution. Can you please check Update2 and Demo Project in my question????

Comment: @Becuzz I have got the original problem but not the solution. Can you please check Update2 and Demo Project in my question????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you have now is an infinite recursion problem.  So it starts out like this:

1. Make a new group which calls the constructor (which calls the base constructor in `EntityBase`).
2. The `EntityBase` constructor gets a validator and then calls its `Validate` method, which ultimately calls into `UniqueName`.
3. The line `context.GroupSet.FirstOrDefault` will create a new `Group` object.  This starts you back at step one again.

This loop of making objects will never stop until you exhaust the stack, which causes the stack overflow exception you got (before you used to hit the connection pool limit before you got the stack overflow and the connection pool problem masked the real problem here).  A couple of things you could try:

First, change the `context.GroupSet.FirstOrDefault` to use `Any` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.  This way step 3 never creates an object and never sends you back to step 1.  While this may solve the problem, it could easily pop back up if you need to do something similar somewhere else.

Second (and by far, preferable) is don't call `Validate` in your constructor.  Typically you should try to validate an object before it is persisted to your database, not on creation (for example, validating a brand new, empty object doesn't do me much good when I'm going to fill it in later.  I need to validate before I save to make sure I don't violate some constraint by putting certain combinations of data into the object.)  In projects I have done we have done something like this:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    //...
    public void Save()
    {
        //Validate here and check for errors
        //If errors exist, throw an exception
        //If no errors, persist to database.
    }
}
```

Obviously you will have to figure out how you want to do this in your project.  Maybe it is through a repository or service, but you are far better off validating before saving instead of on creation.

(Note: I did not try any of this in the code you shared as there is no way I am going to run code that I was handed on the internet.)

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved. I used Any instead of FirstOrDefault() and it works fine.

Comment: As you suggested that calling Validate in constructor is not a good idea, I just commented out the call of Validate method in constructor. Now, in my save method when I call Validate(), I get all the error messages, but those error messages are not displayed as they were displayed when I gave a call to validate in constructor. Can you suggest me some changes in my base class????

Comment: @Vishal I'm not quite clear what you mean by "I get all the error messages, but those error messages are not displayed as they were displayed when I gave a call to validate in constructor. "  Without being able to see what you have done and what the errors are, all I can do is guess.  You should probably ask a new question and include a link back to this one.  That way more people will see the new question and can help as well.  Also, once you have made the new question, comment here with a link or url and I will see it and can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have posted a new question as you suggested and you can find it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349591/error-messages-are-not-reported-to-xaml-when-calling-validate-in-savecommand-ins