# How to fix 'The timeout period elapsed' error C#.net

Tags: pooling

How to fix 'The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool' error. C#.net in windows XP application and .net framework 4.0

Comment: What yo did till now?

Comment: Most of the time this is due to the pool becoming exhausted due to improperly disposed connections, have you verified this is not the case?

Comment: Please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server