# connection timeout error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm having some issues, each time I click on a button it gives me this error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

this minute next minute I'm getting an error. It throws an exception

```
public List<TransactionIssues> GetAllTransactions()
            {
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                List<TransactionIssues> transIssues = new List<TransactionIssues>();
                command.CommandText = "issue_sp_getallunpostedissues";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Connection = connection;
                SqlDataReader rdrObj;

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    rdrObj = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdrObj.Read())
                    {
                        TransactionIssues issues = new TransactionIssues();
                        issues.requisitionNumber = rdrObj.GetString(0);
                        issues.transactionDate = rdrObj.GetDateTime(1);
                        //issues.expense_acccount.account_desc = rdrObj.GetString(2);
                        //issues.expense_acccount.index = rdrObj.GetInt16(3);
                        issues.inventory_acccount.index = rdrObj.GetInt32(2);
                        issues.inventory_acccount.account_desc = rdrObj.GetString(3);
                        issues.docNumber = rdrObj.GetString(4);
                        issues.docType = rdrObj.GetString(5);
                        issues.items = getTransItemByRquisition(rdrObj.GetString(4));
                        transIssues.Add(issues);
                    }
                    rdrObj.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
                return transIssues;
            }
```

Comment: What happens if you dispose of your command after using it (by putting it in a `using` statement, for instance)? It seems your connections stay in use, and you run out of connections in your pool. If increasing the pool size delays this error, you have to figure out why you are keeping them busy...

Comment: Not exactly duplicate but related: [How can I solve a connection pool problem between ASP.NET and SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server)

Comment: but i'm not keeping them, it works on and off

Comment: How to use the using statement; seems i'm doing it incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should dispose of SqlConnection to prevent memory leaks and unclosed connections. "using" keyword takes care of calling "finally" and thus closes your connections:

```
public List<TransactionIssues> GetAllTransactions()
        {
            using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using(var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    List<TransactionIssues> transIssues = new List<TransactionIssues>();
                    command.CommandText = "issue_sp_getallunpostedissues";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Connection = connection;

                        connection.Open();
                        using(SqlDataReader rdrObj = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (rdrObj.Read())
                            {
                                TransactionIssues issues = new TransactionIssues();
                                issues.requisitionNumber = rdrObj.GetString(0);
                                issues.transactionDate = rdrObj.GetDateTime(1);
                                //issues.expense_acccount.account_desc = rdrObj.GetString(2);
                                //issues.expense_acccount.index = rdrObj.GetInt16(3);
                                issues.inventory_acccount.index = rdrObj.GetInt32(2);
                                issues.inventory_acccount.account_desc = rdrObj.GetString(3);
                                issues.docNumber = rdrObj.GetString(4);
                                issues.docType = rdrObj.GetString(5);
                                issues.items = getTransItemByRquisition(rdrObj.GetString(4));
                                transIssues.Add(issues);
                            }
                        }
                        rdrObj.Close();

                    return transIssues;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Should also wrap `rdrObj` in a using block.

Comment: Good catch. Updated :)