# Lots of error regarding the pool size connection

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis, connection-pooling

PS : I know there is a lot of similar question but I can't find my solution.

Since I've changed my database server, I have a lots of that error (5000-8000 per day VS 20-50 per day before the server change) :

> Exception type: InvalidOperationException Exception message: Timeout
> expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection
> from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections
> were in use and max pool size was reached.

This is what I've done :

- Server > properties > connections > maximal number of connections = 0 (unlimited)
- Server > properties > connections > allow remote connections
- Server > properties > connections > timeout = 1200sec (I had 600 but I've increased it)
- All the db connections opened from my code are in "using" statement or well-closed (in a "finally" statement).
- On the web server, nothing has changed, but I've tried to increase the MaxPoolSize to 500 in the connection string. No improvement after that modification...
- still in connection string, I've tried to add TransparentNetworkIPResolution = False but no improvement neither

Note : I am using a dedicated windows user in my connection pool (window authentication) and I don't have those errors with my others applications, on the same web server, communicating with the same sql-server.

I assume there is a configuration relative to SQL server I don't know !
Could you help me ?

Comment: You mention "using" statements on your connections. Are you also invoking `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` in your code? The `SqlDataReader` that's returned is `IDisposable` and also needs to be `Close()`d or disposed of correctly so that it releases its lock on the connection.

Comment: The client connection pool errors may be a symptom that queries are running more slowly on the new server. Rather than focus on connections, I suggest query/index tuning for starters. If the SQL version was changed, there are additional factors to consider.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for the suggest. I've rebuild all indexes. I am gonna check the errors log the next few hours. About queries tuning, it should be not necessary since they were fine on the previous server.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in this link? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server).