Monitoring SQL connection pool usage per connection string
We have a web app running on .NET 6 in Azure on a Linux app service plan.
The application uses multiple different databases/connection strings to Azure SQL databases.
We've seen this exception in our logs, all in context of one specific database:

System.InvalidOperationException Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached

I'm interested in keeping logging some metrics about the connection pool, in order to see if there is a pattern of these connections leaking slowly over time, or all at once.
Looking at the event counters, it seems that the number for connections are across all pools, and would not allow me to keep track of the pool for a specific connection string.
Is there a way to extract information about the connection pool for a specific connection string? Or even loop through pools and get information about them?

Debug suggestions for this type of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server

Maybe look at diagnostic/performance counters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/performance-counters?view=sql-server-ver16 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/event-counters?view=sql-server-ver16

@Charlieface Those are the counters that do not seem to have a granularity per connection string. If I only know the total for all databases, then I have no idea if connection to one specific database is leaking.

I suspect the timeouts is due to azure, but if you start tracking the total number of connections it should be enough to see if something is wrong unless you have a very busy site and it's normal to have a lot of connections. Haven't found a way of tracking specific pool data though

@siggemannen In this particular case, we were getting the error consistently for that database, until the app was restarted. So not a transient error.

you can check sys.sysprocesses or whatever is available on your sql server to see the connections opened. It should give you enough hints to see the different "pools"
